# Do not style pseudo-class :before/:after

Tags: css, css-selectors, styling, pseudo-class

is there any way to style only the base element and not his :before or :after pseudoclasses?

```
<div id="main">bar</div>

#main:before {
  content:'foo'
}
#main {
  background:red;
}
```

I only want to have "bar" underpainted with red, not the "foo" part. Sure I can negate it in another css selector `#main:before{background:white}`, but I would like to have it done in one statement. I tried something like:

```
#main:not(:before) {
  background:red;
}
```

Edit: I need to use it not only for background color, but for font-size etc. as well

Comment: Part of the problem lies in incorrectly calling these pseudo-classes. They are pseudo-elements, and unlike pseudo-classes, they are not allow in the `:not()` pseudo-class. (Which sorta also makes the use of `:not()` incorrect.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need for something like `:not(:before)`. The `#main` selector does that already. To see this, set a non-inheritable property like `border`:

```css
#main { border: 1px solid; }
```

This will draw a border around main. It will not draw another border around the generated content. So the *selector* targets `#main` only. Your generated content has a transparent background (default).

The problem is rather that the generated content lives inside an anonymous box inside `#main`:

```
+-------------+
| +-----+     |
| | foo | bar |
| +-----+     |
+-------------+
```

Basically, this is the same situation as

```html
<div id="main">
    <span class="before">foo</span>
    bar
</div>
```

You can easily see that it's not possible to add a background to the word *bar* only, because `#main`'s background will shine through the span. If you use `#main:not(.before)` as a selector, this will change absolutely nothing.

All you can do is overwrite this by adding a white background to `.before`. Or insert a `span` around *bar*, as suggested in another answer.

Other properties like `font` are subject to inheritance, so technically the cause of the problem is different, but the solution is the same.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no way to refer to the content of an element without its `:before` or `:after` pseudo-elements, except by wrapping that content in an inner element. There just isn’t any selector for the purpose. But note that anything set on the element applies as such to the element as a whole only; only via inheritance (for inheritable properties) will it affect the rendering of the pseudo-elements. The background properties are special case in the sense that they are not inherited but they work almost as if they were, since the initial value is `background: transparent`.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect the DOM you'll see how the ::before pseudo-element is rendered inside #main. That's why your #main:before inherits the background of #main.

I don't see a way around this except adding a span around the 'bar':

```
<div id="main"><span>bar</span></div>

#main:before {
  content:'foo';
}
#main>span {
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is half the way to the solution I am looking for :) I would still prefer something with :not() selector though :)

Comment: even if you had a `:not`, you can't say "this element and not its `:before`".  pseudo-elements are _inside_ their parents.

Comment: The problem with the :not is that it cannot contain pseudo-elements, which is what you'd need. The spec simply doesn't support it, which is the reason for your attempted css not working. See the mdn docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this, depending on the circumstances:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

#main {
  background:red;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 2em;
}

#main:before {
  content:'foo';
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: -2em;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="main">bar</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That would kind of work, but I didn't made myself clear. I need to be able to style them separately with all styles (not only color, but font-size...). Simply to target only main element and only before.